# Module example_android: invalid item 'Flutter for Android' in the dependencies list

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Can anyone help me out to get rid of this problem from Project Structure in Android studio flutter project.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0cGN.jpg)

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjmWm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It won't hide the error but at least you will be able to edit your android module and use the flutter SDK.
Simply open your android module in a new android studio window.

[image: like this]